# jquery blockUI and unblocui

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having issue with unblockUI. It gives compile timne error. syntax error $.unblockUI();

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">  
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  $('#toHide').show().blockUI(); 
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm15").submit()', 100); 
  $.unblockUI(); 
</SCRIPT>
```

Purpose is blockUI for a period of time show laoding please wait message then unblockit or go to next page.

after removing } im getting another error: ie

> $("#toHide").show().blockUI is not a
>   function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unmatched brace. The last line should be

```
$.unblockUI();
```

**EDIT**

```
.blockUI()
```

cannot be called on any object except for the jQuery object. So try:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$.blockUI();
$('#toHide').show(); 
setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm15").submit()', 100); 
$.unblockUI();
```

Comment: yes i made, but after running im getting $("#toHide").show().blockUI is not a function

Answer (score 1):

There's a stray "}" after the call to "unblockUI()".  If that's really in your code, then that would be a problem.

Also, you really should pass functions to "setTimeout()" and not strings:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#safeForm15').submit();
}, 100);
```

You're also using jQuery, so you can call "document.getElementById()" if you want but it's clearly less code if you take advantage of the library.

Comment: yes i made, but after running im getting $("#toHide").show().blockUI is not a function